# Laptop's inbuilt keyboard is not getting disabled

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure

One of my laptop's keys (<kbd>/</kbd>) was continuously getting pressed on its own. Maybe it was stuck or it was dirt, I don't know, so to fix it I disabled my laptop's inbuilt keyboard by following this procedure:

Device Manager -> Keyboards -> Keyboard with PS2 written (it was the inbuilt keyboard) -> Right click -> Uninstall device.

Now it worked perfectly (i.e. laptop's keyboard stopped working) and I began using an external keyboard which was all fine until today when Windows 10 got an update of about 409MB, keyboard enabled itself (I don't know how). And when I try to disable it, it isn't getting disabled.

I tried the same procedure and it says to restart but the keyboard is working on restart too.

How can I completely disable my keyboard ?

Comment: Have you tried a hardware fix, i.e. popping off the\ keytop, and prying underneath with a needle to ease up pressure on the snap-button switch? It will probably destroy at least that key, but, done judiciously, the external keyboard should work.

Comment: no I haven't tried that, some people say that all the keys are connected and one key will damage the working of the entire keyboard ?

Comment: but mainly why Windows keyboard uninstall feature isnt working